# Create a variable from SSIS Derived Column

Tags: sql-server, variables, ssis, etl, derived-column

In my SSIS package, I have a Script Component that creates a +1 new customer ID when the package runs.

I want to assign the numerical value of the ID to a variable. The variable will be used in a File System Task to create a directory with the Customer ID as the folder name.

```
Example - C:\Customer Orders\<CO_ID>
```

I have created a derived column (sequence) transformation in the data flow named (CO_ID). However, I am stuck on the proper syntax for the variable expression.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: you need to create a ID inside the dataflow task and use it outside of it? this operation must be done for each row or what?

Answer (score 0):

Without the error message and more details, it is difficult to say what's wrong. But I think you're trying to convert a number to a string and then concatenate it to another string (the path). If that's the case, your derived column expression should be something like:

```
"c:\Customer Orders\" + (DT_STR, 10,1252) CO_ID
```

If the backslashes give you a problem (can't remember if they need to be escaped), then try doubling them up:

```
"c:\\Customer Orders\\" + (DT_STR, 10,1252) CO_ID
```

Comment: Derived column is used inside a dataflow task, and Execute System Task is on the Control Flow level, so any variable update is not visible to the control flow level until the dataflow task execution is done, so the OP approach will not works. Only if Files system task is executed from a script component

Answer (score 0):

`Derived column Transformation` is used inside a `Dataflow task`, and `Execute System Task` is on the `Control Flow` level, so any variable update is not visible to the `Control Flow` level until the `Dataflow Task` execution is done. So it will only create a directory for the last `CO_ID`.

If you need to create a Directory for each customer, and assuming that you are creating ID inside the script Component. Just create the directory from it using the following code *(Vb.Net)*

```
If Not Io.Directory.Exists("c:\Customer Orders\" & COID.ToString()) Then

   IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(c:\Customer Orders\" & COID.ToString())

End If
```

Else, if you only need to create columns and to loop over them later, i think that you only need to Cast the `CO_ID` column to `DT_WSTR`:

```
"C:\\Customer Orders\\" + (DT_WSTR, 50) [CO_ID]
```

Comment: When my package runs, a +1 customer ID is created to a table. I have created inside a Data Flow Task a Derived Column, CO_ID, with and expression associating it to a table. The Data Type is Unicode string [DT_WSTR] 50 

What I want to do is create a variable that will retrieve the newly created ID using the CO_ID Derived Column. The variable would be used in a File System Task that creates a Directory folder on a server that uses the CO_ID value as its name. Example:
C:\Customer Orders\CO_ID -or- C:\Customer Orders\9878, etc. 

I hope that this make sense and appreciate your assistance.

Comment: If you have a script component. Just assign the value to the variable in the `PostExecute` method. First you have to add this variable to the script `ReadWriteVariables`